# display gridview data in another page or other gridview with row data in editable mode

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a grid view with 10 columns when I click edit it need to display data in another page with the row data in editable mode and also some other columns of the tables.  please help me out from this ...please...,

```
<pre>using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls; 
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace WebApplication1
{
public partial class displaypage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=SRAVI-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=testdb;Integrated Security=True");
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        getdata();
    }
    public void getdata()
    {
        string cmd = "select * from namestb";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, conn);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

    protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("editpage.aspx");
    }
}
} <code>
```

.aspx

```
<pre>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableEventValidation="false"         CodeBehind="displaypage.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.displaypage" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" Height="30px" 
                        ImageUrl="~/images/edit image.jpg" Width="38px" 
                        onclick="ImageButton1_Click" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <br />
    <br />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<code>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add RowCommand Event in GridView.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
      <asp:LinkButton ID ="lnkEdit" runat ="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Recordid")%>' CommandName ="cmdEdit" Text ='Edit'></asp:LinkButton>
</asp:GridView>
```

Here rocordid is the  id of your record.

In Page behind you need to write code.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{


    if (e.CommandName == "cmdEdit")
    {
        string Recordid = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        Response.Redirect("EditPage.aspx?recordid="+Recordid );
    }
}
```

On EditPage you can get recordid from the query string and can fetch the record form the database for further processing.

I hope it will help you

Comment: Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.displaywebform_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'GridView1_RowEditing' and no extension method 'GridView1_RowEditing' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.displaywebform_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: sir Im getting this errorr::: Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'ASP.displaywebform_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'GridView1_RowEditing' and no extension method 'GridView1_RowEditing' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.displaywebform_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: can you provide your code. Without code i can only guess. Please check the name of the Command(CommandName ="cmdEdit"). I think you name the Command to "Edit". If this then you need to Change the command name or add the event 'GridView1_RowEditing'.

Comment: <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:LinkButton ID ="lnkEdit" runat ="server" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("CustomerId")%>' CommandName ="cmdEdit" Text ='Edit'></asp:LinkButton>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            string cmdEdit = "update Customer set FirstName=null, LastName=null, Designation=null, Address=null, City=null, State=null, Country=null where CustomerId=";
            if (e.CommandName == "cmdEdit")
            {
                string Recordid = Convert.ToString(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                Response.Redirect("EditPage.aspx?recordid=" + Recordid);
            }

Comment: You can edit your question and can post your entire .aspx and .cs file code there. It will help us to find the problem in your code.